# Cannot convert value of type '[String : String?]' to expected argument type '[NSObject : AnyObject]?'

Tags: swift, parse-platform, ios9, nsobject

When I use Parse 1.8.5 to upload data to Parse, this cloud code has compile error in "params" that I cannot debug it.

```
       let params = ["phoneNumber" : userPhoneNumber, 
                    "username": username,
                    "password": userPassword,
                    "Email": userEmail
                     ]  

        PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("sendCode", withParameters: params, block: 
              { (response: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if response?.localizedDescription != nil {
                print(error)
                var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Failure", message: "SignUp Error", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alert.show()
            } else {
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 16):

The error message says that there are optional types in the values of `params`.
Make sure that all values are unwrapped.

Answer (score 1):

I had the Same Problem in my project. i just changed my code from               `let parameters = ["email": mail,"password":passCode ]` to                     `let parameters = ["email": mail as! AnyObject,"password":passCode as! AnyObject]` . Not sure if it affects anything else.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.Try this:

```
let parameters = ["number": number, 
                  "username": username,
                  "password": userPassword,
                  "Email": userEmail]
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("sendCode", withParameters: parameters) { results, error in
            if error != nil {  
                 print(error)   
            } else {
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating() 
            }
}
```

Make sure `number`, `username`, `userPassword`, `userEmail`, `sendCode` are in the exact syntax in Parse Cloud

Answer (score 0):

Try this on to cast each element to AnyObject

```
    let params = ["phoneNumber" : userPhoneNumber as! AnyObject, 
                "username": username as! AnyObject,
                "password": userPassword as! AnyObject,
                "Email": userEmail as! AnyObject
                 ]
```